# Fix format errot when saving with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA to save a copy in temp file and email it with outlook. 
The file emailed gives me a error message when I open it. It says

> File extension and File format do not match.

Bellow is my code, if anyone can tell me where I am wrong:

```
Sub EmailWorkbook()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    'Make a copy of the file/Open it/Mail it/Delete it
    'If you want to change the file name then change only TempFileName
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Daily Sales" & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm") & FileExtStr
    FileExtStr = ".xlxs"
    FileFormatNum = 51


    wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "myemail"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "title"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete the file
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The file you receive in the email, it is zero length in size? What might be going wrong is that the file is created okay, but it still open by Excel VBA when doing the attaching. That might mean that it doesn't attach right or is zero length. What I would do is close the file before doing the attaching, and use VBA to verify it exists in the directory and has a file length > 0. Then do the email attaching part.

Comment: `FileExtStr = ".xlxs"` => `FileExtStr = ".xlsx"`?

Comment: Gserg ftw.  .xlxs is not a valid format.